# Is there a way to deploy a (library) update without shutting down the main program

Tags: python, design-patterns, multiprocessing

Here is an example, say, we have two python files:

1. Listener.py -- Keep Listening to some input stream
2. Process.py -- After we receive the data, Listener.py will call functions here and store results to file.

Let say I have to keep "improving/changing" the Process.py, but the Listener.py itself is very stable. Is it possible that we can somehow reload the newer version of Process.py without stopping the listener? (The point here is that if we shut down the listener, we may miss some incoming data)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [reload](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reload) function.
Thus you can check module modification time:

```
os.path.getmtime(filepath)
```

and then if it's different from previous check - reload module:

```
if module_source_is_modified(process):
    process = reload(process)
```